# Describing and referencing exercises in latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would be like reference the exercises have done such that it says

Exercise 1 (Author [number], Chapter i, Exercise i.j )

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts} % if you want blackboard bold symbols e.g. for real numbers
\usepackage{graphicx} % if you want to include jpeg or pdf pictures
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Def}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{cond}[thm]{Condition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{conj}[]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{post}{Postulate 1}
\newtheorem*{post2}{Postulate 2}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}

\title{BLANK} % change this
\author{BLANK} % change this
\date{\today} % change this

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\mres}{\mathbin{\vrule height 1.6ex depth 0pt width
        0.13ex\vrule height 0.13ex depth 0pt width 1.3ex}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proj}

\begin{document}
\begin{ex}
Let $F_1, F_2, \dots$ be $1$-sets in the plane such that $F =
\end{ex}
\begin{proof}
If all the $F_i$'s are regular, each $F_i$ may be covered by a countable union of 
rectifiable curves except for a set of zero measure. Thus $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i$ 
may be covered by a countable union of rectifiable curves, except for a countable of 
zero measure sets; thus by positivity of a measure and countable subadditivity, this 
is a set of zero measure. Since $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i$ is a $1$-set by Theorem 
4.2.13, it is a regular set.

Now if all the $F_i$ are irregular, let $\Gamma$ is a rectifiable curve then
$\mathcal{H}^1(\Gamma \cap F_i)=0$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}^1(\Gamma \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i) = 
\mathcal{H}^1(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(\Gamma \cap F_i)) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}
\mathcal{H}^1(\Gamma \cap F_i)=0
\end{equation}
Therefore, again by Theorem 4.2.13, we have that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i$ is 
irregular.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please create a document that contains some exercises in it? Do so by avoiding the use of `\mres` (since it's not needed in your code snippet). The same goes for the `float`, `amsfonts` and `graphicx` packages, I presume. Your example should be [minimal](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supply an optional argument to the `ex` environment. This is referred to as a "theorem note":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

See Exercise~\ref{exercise:ABC}.

\begin{ex}[Author~ABC, Chapter~X, Exercise~Y.Z]
  \label{exercise:ABC}\lipsum[1]
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

When you reference **Exercise 1** though, you won't get the theorem note as part of the reference. However, that seems sufficient otherwise you'll clutter flow of your text.

Comment: Apologies. I didnt mean reference within the text. I really just meant to label the exercises.

Comment: @1234: So I guess using the optional argument is sufficient then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that